# Remove all of the specific characters at the end of the string

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, replace, trim

Since `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` don't work on my code, I Need to find a way to remove specific characters from my string but only at the end.

The characters in question are `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(32)`.
The fortunate thing is that they always occur in that combination/order.

I don't want to replace all of those combinations in my string, I only want to remove them at the end.

I was thinking of `REVERSE` and `PATINDEX` with a pattern, but I am not sure if that is the best way? And what would be the REGEX for this combination?

DBMS: MSSQL 2012

Comment: Which dbms? (LTRIM and RTRIM are not ANSI SQL functions.)

Answer (score 0):

A scalar function could do this;

```
create function dbo.MyTrim(@text varchar(max)) returns varchar(max)
as
-- function to remove all occurences of (char(10) + char(13) + char(32)) from the right end of the input.
begin

    while (right(@text, 3) = char(10) + char(13) + char(32))
    begin
        set @text = left(@text, len(@text) - 2)
    end

    return @text

end
go

declare @MyValue varchar(100); set @MyValue = 'Hello world!' + char(10) + char(13) + char(32)
select datalength(@MyValue), datalength(dbo.MyTrim(@MyValue))

set @MyValue = @MyValue + char(10) + char(13) + char(32)
select datalength(@MyValue), datalength(dbo.MyTrim(@MyValue))

set @MyValue = @MyValue + char(10) + char(13) + char(32)
select datalength(@MyValue), datalength(dbo.MyTrim(@MyValue))
```

Note that the [LEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) function does not include trailing spaces, hence -2 not -3.

Comment: The problem is that it could be more than one occurence at the end.